# Is a granted bounty and the reputation withdrawn when I delete my answer?

Tags: support, bounty

Is a granted bounty or more specific the reputation withdrawn when I delete my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When an answer that received a bounty is deleted, all reputation including the bounty are revoked. (This may take 5 minutes to be visible.) The bounty is not given back to the user who awarded it.

(from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065))

However, there is an exception to the above.

> Actions taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation [...]  unless the post meets the following criteria (in which case the reputation affects will be permanent):

- The post had a score of at least +3
- The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days

(from [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237))